# How to add custom row data to the CursorResultTableFormatter

Tags: lightningchart

This is the example for how to format the Result Table. But I can't figure out how to add custom data? For example RSI, or MACD or anything to the candle.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
OHLCSeries.setCursorResultTableFormatter((tableBuilder, series, ohlcSegment) => {
     return tableBuilder
         .addRow(`Pointing at`, '', series.getName())
         .addRow(`X:`, '', ohlcSegment.getPosition())
         .addRow(`Open:`, '', ohlcSegment.getOpen())
         .addRow(`High:`, '', ohlcSegment.getHigh())
         .addRow(`Low:`, '', ohlcSegment.getLow())
         .addRow(`Close:`, '', ohlcSegment.getClose())
 })
```

In this case I wish I could do something like

```
.addRow('myCustomVariable:', '', ohlcSegment.myCustomVariable)
```

Comment: I have yet to find a solution.... anyone?